# Function execution order in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have 3 functions:

```
function selected_feature_intervencoes(event){

    store_intervencoes.removeAll();
    for(var i=0; i<ruas_intervencoes.selectedFeatures.length; i++){

        trecho_selecionado = parseInt(ruas_intervencoes.selectedFeatures[i].attributes.k_n_rua);
        toponimo_selecionado = ruas_intervencoes.selectedFeatures[i].attributes.toponimia;
        valor_trecho += parseFloat(ruas_intervencoes.selectedFeatures[i].attributes.orcamento_total);
        ajaxFunction();
        }                   
    };

function ajaxFunction(){
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: 'php/grid.php',
        method: 'GET',
        success: sucesso(i),
        failure: fracasso,
        params: {'k_n_rua': trecho_selecionado[i]}
        });
    }


function sucesso (result, request) {

    jsonData = Ext.util.JSON.decode(result.responseText);            
    if (!jsonData.rows) {
        jsonData = Ext.util.JSON.decode('{"rows" :[{"fk_n_rua":"' + trecho_selecionado[] +  '","nome_intervencao":"","prioridade":"","orcamento":"","toponimia":"' + toponimo_selecionado + '"}]}');
}
 store_intervencoes.loadData(jsonData, true);       
 document.getElementById('total_intervencoes').value = valor_trecho.toFixed(2) + ' €';

}
```

The `for` in `selected_feature_intervencoes(event)` function executes the other two functions in this order:

```
ajaxFunction();
ajaxFunction();
sucesso ();
sucesso ();
```

But I want to execute them in this order:

```
ajaxFunction();
sucesso ();
ajaxFunction();
sucesso ();
```

Can somebody tell me how I do that?

Comment: make your ajax functions synchronous

Comment: add this to your ajax call :     async:false

Comment: One problem is that you're not calling the `success` callback correctly -- it's executing immediately when you call your AJAX function instead of when it has completed. I think you should have just `success: sucesso` instead (no parenthesis).

Comment: Don't do that. Synchronous AJAX are silly.

Comment: AJAX is supposed to be asynchronous. Making them synchronous defeats the whole purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a promise library like [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q). Q lets you chain asynchronous calls together, the syntax would look something like this:

```
Q.fcall(ajaxFunction)
    .then(sucesso)
    .then(ajaxFunction)
    .then(sucesso)
    .done();
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a direct call to the server instead of using AJAX. This way it will wait till the response is received before going to the next step.